# Jenkins role based authorization - How to restrict access of a particular project to a group?

Tags: jenkins, role-based-access-control

I have a jenkins setup with role based authorization in place. 
With this I am able to restrict access of a particular project to a particular **user**. 
But I am not able to do the same for a **group**/**role**.

Refer the image below, where 'arushi' is a user who belongs to the role 'developer'. 
I wish to grant 'Sample' project's access to all the users with role 'developer' and not just to the user 'arushi'. Not able to do the same with this. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: The "developer" is a role, not a user group (as in your first screenshot - Arushi has developer role whereas Sumaiya got admin role). Refer this if this helps - https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2017/03/jenkins-users-groups-roles/

Comment: @Pankaj I am looking for a way I can restrict project access of all the users in the role 'developer'. This link did not help in that case. It also mentions how a user (similar to user 'arushi' in my case) can be restricted to access.

Comment: I added further points in my answer below; If you want to make use of groups your LDAP or AD (authentication provided) should provide them. You can't create groups in Jenkins's local database afaik.

Comment: @Pankaj I don't want to use the LDAP method. I want the same role that I created with the help of role-based authorization plugin, to be used for restriction of project access too. Or if there's any other method of grouping users into roles and then granting access to projects?

Answer (score 0):

The "developer" is a role, not a user group (as in your first screenshot - Arushi has the developer role whereas Sumaiya has the admin role).

Refer to this for more explanation - https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2017/03/jenkins-users-groups-roles/

User groups represent authorities provided by the Security Realm (e.g. LDAP plugin can provide groups), which means if you want to use groups, they should be in your LDAP/AD.